# javascript jquery fade in fade out

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tooltip

hey 
i have some fading tool-tips but the problem is when you roll over the buttons in a line it has to fade out complete before it can fade back in so in makes a sort of flashing 
this is the code

```
showbox:function($, $tooltip, e){
    $tooltip.fadeIn(this.fadeinspeed)
    this.positiontooltip($, $tooltip, e)
},
hidebox:function($, $tooltip){              
    if (!this.isdocked){
    $tooltip.fadeOut(this.fadeoutspeed)
    $tooltip.css({borderColor:'black'}).find('.stickystatus:eq(0)').css({background:this.stickybordercolors[0]}).html(this.stickynotice1)
    }
},
```

is there a way of fading out but if it starts fading back in without having to completely fading out 
thanks for any help im kinda a JavaScript noob
thanks

Answer (score 1):

You probably want [jQuery.stop](http://api.jquery.com/stop/): `$tooltip.stop(true);`

Answer (score 1):

Check out the `.stop()` command. http://api.jquery.com/stop/

Comment: thanks dude ive added that and tried using if statements  `hidebox:function($, $tooltip){          
  if (!this.isdocked){
   if (!this.isdocked){
    $tooltip.stop(true);
   }
  $tooltip.fadeOut(this.fadeoutspeed)
  $tooltip.css({borderColor:'black'}).find('.stickystatus:eq(0)').css({background:this.stickybordercolors[0]}).html(this.stickynotice1)
  }`       it now fades out but it can get stuck on the fade back in and i have tried adding opacity to the second if statement but no luck any tips on getting the opacity to 100% there is more code so it may be part of that not sure thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use the [`.stop()`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) method, good examples on that page.